# How to interpolate vector by y in R

Tags: r, interpolation, purrr

I have a vector with coordinates

```
x <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
y <- c(2.6, 7.3, 6.8, 1.9)
```

I need to interpolate vector (x, y) by `x` and by `y` at the same time. By `x` I can do

```
approxfun(x, y)(1:7)
```

But how to interpolate by `y`? I need to obtain `n = floor(abs(y1 - y2))` points between neighboring `y1` and `y2`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your desired output is here. What are the values you would like to receive in this particular case? So you want to just flip your approxfun? `approxfun(y, x)`? Or what kind of modeling assumption are you making?

Comment: Yes, I just want to flip approxfun and obtain increased number of (x, y) coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `purrr::pmap` combined with `dplyr::lag` to interpolate between `x[i-1]` and `x[i]`.
For a linear interpolation between two points, it doesn't matter to cut the interval by `x` or by `y`, so that `approxfun(x, y)` still works :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

x <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
y <- c(2.6, 7.3, 6.8, 1.9)


df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

df %>% mutate(xprev = lag(x),yprev=lag(y)) %>% 
  purrr::pmap(~with(list(...),{
    if (is.na(xprev)) {
      data.frame(x=x,y=y)
    } else {
      n <-  floor(abs(yprev-y)) + 2
      if (n>0) {
        xstep <- (x-xprev) / n  
        xsteps <- seq(xprev+xstep,x ,by = xstep )       
        data.frame(x=xsteps, y=approxfun(c(xprev,x),c(yprev,y))(xsteps))
      }
    }
  })) %>% bind_rows 
#>     x     y
#> 1 1.0 2.600
#> 2 1.5 3.775
#> 3 2.0 4.950
#> 4 2.5 6.125
#> 5 3.0 7.300
#> 6 5.5 5.575
#> 7 6.0 4.350
#> 8 6.5 3.125
#> 9 7.0 1.900
```

Comment: Perfect! But fix `n <- floor(abs(yprev - y)) + 2` to include original points